Correct method for structure optimization using DFT tools
Lets's say I want to start off DFT calculations for a material whose experimental cell constants are known. So I have two ways to get the correct structure to later on calculate, say, band structure at the end. First way is to use these experimental cell constants, take initial atomic positions from a computational database, perform only position relaxation (relax or ISIF=2) and accept the final structure as optimized even though there can be OBVIOUS non-neglectable external pressure on the final structure (since chosen pseudopotential could have yield different lattice constants). Second way is to take both lattice constants and atomic positions from database and perform full structure relaxation (vc-relax or ISIF=3) to get the final structure and accept it as optimized structure (with respect to pseudopotential chosen) even though it does not EXACTLY reproduce the experimental lattice parameter and band structure in the end.

What you described is the ionic relaxation where only the positions of the ions change (calculation='relax' in QE) in contrast to variable cell relaxation (calculation='vc-relax' in QE) where both the ions and the lattice parameters change. There is no single correct way. Both of them have their usage case. See this MMSE question, and this external link for related discussion.

Experimental lattice constants is not necessary global minima based on DFT. For qualitative good result use DFT minima lattice vectors.

I think I may not have communicated the question well. Please have a look at the edited body of the question.

It is also not necessary that experimental lattice constants will give experimental band gap value. My preferences are with DFT based minima structure.

Thanks for response. Also using experimental lattice parameters (even if they  somehow yield reasonable band structure), the phonon or mechanical properties calculations can not be reliable, as they considered the structure with non-neglectable external pressure, correct?
